# Is there another module to auto refresh a page besides Views Auto-Refresh?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I am currently using the [Auto-Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module to build an page that stays up-to-date, without needing to be reloaded.  However, this module will not cooperate with Features.  Is there another module or method I can use the build a page with auto-refreshing content?

Comment: you want to refresh the entire page using ajax or refreshing a block in a page?

Comment: Just a block really, but its a table created by a view

Comment: which release are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.26

Comment: no I mean auto refresh module?

Comment: version = "7.x-1.0-beta2" datestamp = "1366653313"

Comment: try to use version 7.x-1.x-dev instead, if you look at the modules issue you will find that this issue has been resolved.